# My activityIndicator don't resize

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a activityIndicator for my login fuction, but when i rotate my device my activityIndicator don't resize.
this is my code of my login function, from i call it.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    var valid: Bool = false
    self.viewUtils.showActivityIndicator(self.view)
    username =  userField.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    password = passwordTextField.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())


        if (self.username.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty){
            self.showAlert("Inserte usuario password")
        }
        else{

            var user = UserFunction()
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)){
                valid = user.userValid(self.username,password: self.password)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    if valid {
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTable", sender: self )}
                    else{
                    self.showAlert("usuario incorrecto")

                    }


                }
            }
    }
}
```

and this is my code of my showactivity:

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView){
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    activityIndicator.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);

    loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    container.addSubview(loadingView) 
    uiView.addSubview(container)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Storyboard to load your view, or are you adding `NSLayoutConstraint` programmatically?

Comment: the problem is tht i dont have constraint :S

Comment: I think both answers suggest you use `NSLayoutContraint`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have written the above snippet without `NSLayoutConstraint`, the shortest solution would be to respond to:

```
- viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator
```

**Storyboard solution**

A more elegant solution is to use `Storyboard` + `Autolayout` and exactly **3 lines of code**, 1 being optional:

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView){
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(loadingView); // Only if covered
    loadingView.hidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

[image]

You can move the round corners, colors and more to `-viewDidLoad`.

```
loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Define layout constraints for you activityIndicator in this way:

```
activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;    
[activityIndicator addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: activityIndicator
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: container
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]]];

[activityIndicator addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: activityIndicator
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: container
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]]];
```